# How to decrypt push notifications content like What's app messages [React Native]

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on a React Native chat app, and I generate a `privateKey` for encrypting the messages locally and then send them to the server.

Once on the server, I want to send the content of the message, that is encrypted, to receiver through push notification service, but the problem is that the message is encrypted and the server isn't able to decrypt it without using privateKey.

Is it possible to decrypt the push notification content once received on iPhone/Android?
Or is there another solution?

Thank you

Comment: if I understood well, every time you are sending a message you are generating a privateKey. why don't you use allways the same secret privateKey and declare it in both .env files of your frontend and backend project so you can decrypt from wherever you want

Comment: No I always use the same private key for all chat, the problem is that how can I decrypt message content in push notifications if it's the server that send them.

Comment: what is the difference between getting data from server or from app ? why can you only decrypt data when it is from the app

Comment: You don't get it, If on the server I have the encrypted messages, and I can't decrypt them because I don't have the private key, how can I send push notifications using server with decrypted message?

Comment: that why I suggest to not generate the privateKey but make it constant. store it in both your frontend and backend so you can use it to encrypt with and decrypt with from frontend and backend

Comment: Again you don't get it